# Why is strtok causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

Why does the below code give Seg. Fault at last line?

```
char* m=ReadName();
printf("\nRead String %s\n",m); // Writes OK
char* token;
token=strtok(m,'-');
```

As said, read string prints w/o problem, but why cannot split to tokens?

Comment: What does ReadName() do?  How does it allocate the return value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) modifies its first argument, hence it should be modifiable.

Maybe ReadName() returns a pointer to a read-only char array.Can you show us your ReadName() function.

*If* that is the reason for seg-faullt, you can create a copy of the char array before you pass it to strtok using the [strdup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) function like:

```
char *copy = strdup(m);
token = strtok(copy,'-');
....
....
free(copy); // free the copy once you are done using it.
```

Answer (score 2):

`token=strtok(m,'-');` should generate a compiler warning because the second parameter of [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) is a `const char *` pointing to multiple delimiters, not a single `char` delimiter:

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
```

The ASCII code of `'-'` is 0x2D, so passing it as the second parameter of `strtok()` will cause `strtok()` to dereference the address 0x0000002D, which will cause a segfault or access violation on most modern operating systems. To fix this, use a string literal instead of a character literal: `token=strtok(m,"-");`

There's also the issue of how the return value of `ReadName()` is allocated, which others have addressed in their answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know for sure without knowing what `m` points to. But the most likely reason is that `m` is pointing to readonly memory.  So you can print it out, but you can't write to it.

`strtok` writes to the string, so it's faulting, but printf only reads from it, so it isn't.

Try this

```
char* m=ReadName();
printf("\nRead String %s\n",m); // Writes OK
char temp = m[0];
m[0] = temp; // I'll bet you segfault here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because `ReadName()` return string. So, the assignment makes `m` const char* and hence, you **cannot** alter any of its values (modify the string). So, when 'strtok' tries to modify 'm', *Segmentation Fault* is there

Remedy:

```
char *m = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
strcpy(m, ReadName());
```

OR

```
char *m = strdup(ReadName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below is taken from a BSD licensed string processing library for C, called [zString](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString).

https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString

Looking at the implementation of the function, you can see that `strtok()` (or in this case `zstring_strtok()`) relies on a `static *char` to preserve the last location of the delimiter and actually modifies the original string.

```
char *zstring_strtok(char *str, const char *delim) {
    static char *static_str=0;      /* var to store last address */
    int index=0, strlength=0;       /* integers for indexes */
    int found = 0;                  /* check if delim is found */

    /* delimiter cannot be NULL
    * if no more char left, return NULL as well
    */
    if (delim==0 || (str == 0 && static_str == 0))
        return 0;

    if (str == 0)
        str = static_str;

    /* get length of string */
    while(str[strlength])
        strlength++;

    /* find the first occurance of delim */
    for (index=0;index<strlength;index++)
        if (str[index]==delim[0]) {
            found=1;
            break;
        }

    /* if delim is not contained in str, return str */
    if (!found) {
        static_str = 0;
        return str;
    }

    /* check for consecutive delimiters
    *if first char is delim, return delim
    */
    if (str[0]==delim[0]) {
        static_str = (str + 1);
        return (char *)delim;
    }

    /* terminate the string
    * this assignmetn requires char[], so str has to
    * be char[] rather than *char
    */
    str[index] = '\0';

    /* save the rest of the string */
    if ((str + index + 1)!=0)
        static_str = (str + index + 1);
    else
        static_str = 0;

        return str;
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c) explains the deifference between `char s[]` and `char *s` quite well. So,

```
char s[]="Test to pass strtok()"; /* this can be passed to strtok() */
char *m="Test to pass strtok()"; /* passing this will result in SIGSEGV */
```