# strtok() - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strtok giving Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385697/strtok-giving-segmentation-fault)

I try to use strtok function to split string in many tokens but in this example it returns me a seg. fault error. Where i'm in wrong??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int i=0;
    char * string = "HI:HOW:ARE:YOU:?", *tmp;

    while(1){
        if(i==0) tmp=strtok(string,":");
        else tmp=strtok(NULL,":");
        if(tmp==NULL) break;
        printf("%s\n",tmp);
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `strtok` modifies the string passed to it, and you're passing it a string literal.

Comment: Soooooo many dupes of this question. Also, please **do read the documentation** of the functions you're trying to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
char * string = "HI:HOW:ARE:YOU:?"
```

for

```
char string [] = "HI:HOW:ARE:YOU:?"
```

With char string [] you have an array, and char * you have a pointer. When you declare an array, it will request space to allocate the size of your string. The char * string creates a pointer that points to a literal string.

The problem with char *string it is that the point should not be changed  because string literals are typically stored in **read-only memory**, thus causing [undefined behavior 33](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/CC.+Undefined+Behavior#CCUndefinedBehavior-ub30)

( for more detail read this https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR30-C.+Do+not+attempt+to+modify+string+literals )

Therefore, since with **strtok** the contents of the string is modified and broken into smaller strings (tokens) you got problems.

Comment: I have faced this problem,too. Thanks for the explanation!